# Just me, a schizophrenic and a petty arsonist

Tags: commas, subjects

> Just me, a schizophrenic and a petty arsonist.

How many people are there in the above sentence? Is it ambiguous?

Comment: yes,  ambiguous there are 2 or 3 persons

Comment: Could just be one person.

Comment: What happened to the strippers, JFK, and Stalin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could imagine anywhere from 1 to 3 people:

One:

Just me (further describing myself as a schizophrenic and arsonist)

Two:

Just me (describing myself as a schizophrenic), and another person who is an arsonist

Just me, and another person who is both a schizophrenic and arsonist

Three:

Me, a schizophrenic, and an arsonist

Comment: Ah, but #3 is the same as #1.